# What should I convert my framework project to swift 2.3 or 3?

Tags: swift

I have a framework project and want to convert to support swift 2.3 and 3. 
given the consumer of my SDK might be on swift 2.3 or 3, what should I convert my framework to? do I need to create 2 frameworks for distribution?

Comment: It should be impossible coexist two another swift version. Xcode alert swift version error. yes, you should prepare two versions of framework for swift version.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to prepare two versions of Framework. While opening your code in Xcode8 you will see convert option, do not click on that. Compile your code and you will see the potential warnings and errors.

You can resolve it using the compiler command

```
#if swift(>=3.0)

  // Add your code to work in swift3

#else

 // Add your code to work in the swift 2.3. This one you already have.

#endif
```